# Developer Sandbox Issue: Email Privileges Revoked

Tags: sandbox, error-messages

Sending emails works fine in production (Enterprise Edition) but for some reason, I seem to not have the send email option in the corresponding Developer sandbox. This is what I see in the latter, no Send an Email button:

[image]

Additionally, when I click a custom link that easily sends an email in production, the very same link throws up the following error in sandbox:

**Email Privileges Revoked. Your organization's email privileges have been revoked due to non-compliance with our Terms of Use.**

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Setup | Email Administration | Deliverability.

By default, new Sandboxes have emails disabled to prevent you from inadvertently sending out mails from your test / development system.