# Service Cloud Console: Data Not Available Error while replying to case via email

Tags: email2case, service-cloud-console

In Sandbox:- 
Create a case via 'Email To Case'.

However, when user tries to answer via email(using service cloud console), following error is coming. Strange enough, case can be answered via 'Portal'.

```
    "The data you were trying to access could not be found. 
It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. 
If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page."
```

What can be possible reason?

Comment: Just a thought - did you remember to disable the "helpful" email thing set by SF when you refresh a sandbox? Go to Setup -> Deliverability and make sure Access level = all email?

Comment: @eyescream, well thanks. That helped. Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hits me every time ;)

Recently (Spring'13) SF decided to be helpful in the emails area. Every time you refresh a sandbox they set the Email Deliverability to only system emails. You need to flip it in the Setup -> Deliverability (Access level = all email).

Without this the "send an email" button is gone on the Activity History rel. list and all other quirky things happen...

See also [NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION Error from Unit Test on SingleMailMessage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8959/no-mass-mail-permission-error-from-unit-test-on-singlemailmessage) and [Developer Sandbox Issue: Email Privileges Revoked](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14965/developer-sandbox-issue-email-privileges-revoked)