# Can we change from email address of the approval process approver notification?

Tags: approval-process, email-alert

[image]currently the approval notification which is going to current approver has from email address has current users email address.

If approval has multiple steps, each step notification will have previous approver's email address as from address.

Can we change this? like other workflow email alert?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Were you able to find any solution? I tried by changing the from by using a custom header as described here (http://goo.gl/gtt22W) but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating an "Organization-Wide Address" (an email address). You'll have to prove that this mailbox is accessible for you (SF will send an email with link that has to be clicked within 72h).

Then, in the approval process start defining / reusing an email alert...

[image]

Comment: I have credentials in your org now? :P

Comment: @user320 copying is the best form of flattery, eh? ;)

Comment: Hi eyescream, This will work for email alerts, but for approver notification we dont have option to select from address. right?.. we can only define email tempalte.

Comment: It depends whether you select an existing email alert or you click "Add new"... "Add new" will let you specify the from (as I've written, on the bottom of the page), editing of existing email alert should also start to show this select box. "Email template" and "email alert" are 2 different (but related) things. If you don't see the "from email address" field at all - are you in a sandbox? It might be something to do with http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/22094/799.

Comment: Hm, I saw you'r edit & screenshot. You're talking about the initial submission notification email, not email alerts in the approval steps, record rejection etc? That one might be trickier to change the "From"... Try keeping that template blank and instead defining new action (Email alert) under "initial submission actions"?

Comment: Since I am using email approval process, how it will work if i keep notification template blank? and it seems even though i keep this blank it will send out automatic standard email template.

Comment: From what I remember the initial notification will be sent anyway, even without template. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrfiAAC, https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq74AAC. You could try making first step dummy? Configure it to automatically skip record maybe... No idea man, you'll have to experiment but I think it's hard to avoid the first email :(

Comment: @eyescream I'm having the same issue. Using the email alert in the initial submission actions wouldn't work for me since I need the "approve via e-mail" functionality and I'm also assigning the approvers through code (+ initiating the approval) I find it a bit strange that there is no way to use a different from address for the approval email template :(. I wonder what deva ended up doing.