# unable to send email to email in triggers

Tags: trigger

```
trigger sendEmail on Company__c(after insert, after update) 
{    
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for(Company__c e : trigger.new)
    {   
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
        attach.setFileName('Employee.pdf');

        String body;

        body = '<html><h1 style=\"text-align:center;\">Employee Information</h1><br/><br/><table align=\"center\"><tr><td>Employee Name</td><td>' + e.Name + '</td></tr><tr><td>Age</td><td>' + e.Age__c + '</td></tr><tr><td>State</td><td>' + e.State__c + '</td></tr><tr><td>City</td><td>' + e.City__c + '</td></tr></table></html>';
        System.debug('HTML is ' + body);

        attach.Body = Blob.toPDF(body);

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[] { e.Email__c });
        mail.setSubject('PDF Generation');
        mail.setHtmlBody('PFA');
        mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach });     

        mails.add(mail);  
    }
    if(!mails.isEmpty())
    {
        Messaging.SendEmail(mails);
    }
}
```

unable to send email to email in triggers. this is my code. pls help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Service Cloud Console: Data Not Available Error while replying to case via email](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22084/service-cloud-console-data-not-available-error-while-replying-to-case-via-email)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, it works fine on my end. If you test it on sandbox did you check the Email Administration - Deliverability? It could be on Sandbox that it is switched off as no access.

[image]